# Why is this lambda function not an error in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I imagined this code

```
let x: (a: { b: number }) => void = (a: { b: number, c: string }) => { alert(a.c) };
x({ b: 123 });
```

should produce an error, since the lambda function requires an additional property on the `a` argument, so the signatures should not be compatible. But trying this in the latest typescript playground does not produce any errors! Why is that?

Comment: Strictly speaking the actual function does match the type of x as far as structural typing is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

When you said

`let x: (a: { b: number }) => void`

You are saying "x is a function that takes an object with a `b` key."

You then assigned it a lambda that took an object with a `b` key and a `c` key. That passes the typechecker because any object that gets passed in must have a `b` key.

Then you pass it an object with a `b` key. There's no error.

If you want it to fail because of the `c` key, make the type of `x` the following:

`let x: (a: { b: number, c: string }) => void`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get *why* this would not be an error. The lambda that requires a c key couldn't be passed an object with just a b key, so how come it can be assigned to the type of x, which accepts that? My thinking is that the argument types are a set of guarantees that the lambda can assume. Assigning it to x breaks that, so it should not be permitted.

Comment: It's because you're giving a more precise lambda to a variable with a less precise type. Imagine if you said `let x: Animal = new Cat()`. That would obviously be fine, even though `Animal` may not have all the properties of `Cat`. Assigning a lambda that requires more properties to a variable who's type requires less is not an error either.

Comment: Sure, that totally makes sense for objects, but shouldn't it be the opposite way for functions? In objects, you can't do `let x: Cat = new Animal()`, but you can do the opposite, because then no matter the specifics of the Cat, it will be able to do all that Animal can do. In functions, a function `f` that takes an animal as parameter could take a cat, but a function `g` that takes specifically a cat couldn't take any animal. In other  words, *`f` could handle all inputs `g` could, but not the other way around*.  Therefore, It seems to me that `f = g` should be acceptable, but not `g = f`.